# How to navigate from multiple nested navigator to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to navigate between multiple nested navigator on react navigation ?

it's so much like this:

### Parent Navigator:

- screen 1
- screen 2
- **navigator A**

  - screen 3
  - screen 4
  - **Navigator B**

    - screen 5
    - screen 6

---

So here I want to navigate from screen 5 to screen 2 on React navigation 5

Comment: mention type of each navigators, like
is it tab, stack or drawer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`dangerouslyGetParent()`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetparent). Something like:

```js
// in screen 5
const parent = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent()
parent.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)
```